# IIS 7 session timeout setting from UI

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, iis-7

I am trying to update session timeout setting in IIS 7(to maximum value) from UI as per below article

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx

It says the timeout setting is in `hh:mm:ss` but I can give `365.00:00:00` as the max session timeout value. Does that mean my session timeout setting is 365 days or 365 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a "[TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)" format, so in the case of "365.00:00:00" It will be 365 days. If you wanted 365 hours it would be something like: 15.05:00:00... so 15 days and 5 hours.